# Return the rows which are not shipped

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I need to return rows which are not shipped based on the request.

if the request comes like i need 3 layers then i need to check shipping status and return layers which are not shipped based on type. Here  types 'o' are total layers and 's' are already shipped

output
1003
1004
1001

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anti-join. For example:

```
select a.*
from mytable a
left join mytable b on b.id = a.id and b.type = 's'
where a.type = 'o' and b.type is null
```

Result:

```
 id  layer  type 
 --- ------ ---- 
 1   1001   o    
 2   1002   o    
 3   1003   o
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e086c95a6efc9c5cdb3cd6881dc1eb54).

Comment: Thank you, it worked.